# How can I compile a large open source project quickly after I modify some source files?

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, open-source, ceph

I've just learned `cmake` and `make` for a few days.

I want to modify some source files in `ceph` (written in C++), and compile them to study how `ceph` works. But it takes too much time to compile it even I just make some minor changes. How should I do?

Or, I want to compile some submodules of `ceph` into dynamic link library(`.so`), and then replace the originals with them. How can I make it?

Thanks!

————————————————————————————————————————————
I add one line of code in a certain source file:

`cout << 'test' << endl`

and run make(I have make for several times before)

`make`

outputs in shell:

```
[bop@client1 jewel]$ make
Making all in .
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/bop/jewel'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bop/jewel'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory \`/home/bop/jewel/src\'
make  all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/bop/jewel/src'
Making all in ocf
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/bop/jewel/src/ocf'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/bop/jewel/src/ocf'
..............
..............
./make_version -g ./.git_version
This is no git repository, not updating .git_version
if [ -n "$NO_VERSION" ] ; then \
    ./make_version -g ./.git_version -c ./ceph_ver.h -n ; \
else \
    ./make_version -g ./.git_version -c ./ceph_ver.h ; \
fi
This is no git repository, not updating .git_version
  CXX      erasure-code/jerasure/libec_jerasure_generic_la-ErasureCodeJerasure.lo
  CXXLD    libec_jerasure_generic.la
  CXX      erasure-code/jerasure/libec_jerasure_sse3_la-ErasureCodeJerasure.lo
  CXXLD    libec_jerasure_sse3.la
  CXX      erasure-code/jerasure/libec_jerasure_sse4_la-ErasureCodeJerasure.lo
  CXXLD    libec_jerasure_sse4.la
  CXXLD    liberasure_code.la
  CXXLD    librados.la
..............
..............
writing... rados.8 { } ceph-fuse.8 { } ceph-syn.8 { } ceph-disk.8 { } rbd.8 { } crushtool.8 { } radosgw.8 { } ceph-rest-api.8 { } ceph-deploy.8 { } ceph-osd.8 { } ceph-conf.8 { } rbd-replay-prep.8 { } ceph-detect-init.8 { } rbdmap.8 { } radosgw-admin.8 { } ceph-dencoder.8 { } osdmaptool.8 { } ceph-post-file.8 { } rbd-replay.8 { } ceph-mds.8 { } ceph-rbdnamer.8 { } rbd-fuse.8 { } librados-config.8 { } ceph-run.8 { } ceph-authtool.8 { } ceph.8 { } rbd-replay-many.8 { } rbd-nbd.8 { } ceph-mon.8 { } mount.ceph.8 { } ceph-clsinfo.8 { } ceph-create-keys.8 { } monmaptool.8 { } rbd-mirror.8 { } ceph-debugpack.8 { } cephfs.8 { } 
build succeeded.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bop/jewel/man'
Making all in doc
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/bop/jewel/doc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bop/jewel/doc'
Making all in systemd
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/bop/jewel/systemd'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bop/jewel/systemd'
```

When it is running, I see the CPU utilization is very low, but the disk load is fairly high. The whole process takes me about 30 minutes.

I don't think it's acceptable. How can I reduce the cost?

Thanks!

Comment: No. You're very unlikely to have exactly same environment as your current binaries are compiled, and mixing them is dangerous. Always do a full build, or don't build at all and let the CI do the job.

Comment: If you can tolerate the pain of compiling everything once, then you'll only have to wait for the compiler to process what you've changed on subsequent builds. Is that more acceptable to you?

Comment: This is where .h(pre-compiled header) come into play, they can help you a lot, http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0005/Improving_build_times_with_pre-compiled_headers.htm

Comment: If you edit the code inside test.cpp and you only have its .h file being used in other parts of the program the compiler does not have to recompile every place test.h is used all it has to do is compile test.cpp and test.h, that's it.

Comment: Try `make -j4`.